# Scaling data in R gives spurious Error "length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'"

Tags: r, scale

I am trying to scale a data.frame in the range of 0 and 1 using the following code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  x <- data[i, ]
  data[i, ] <- scale(x, min(x), max(x)-min(x))
}

Data:
 x1   x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9  x10  x11  x12  x13  x14  x15  x16  x17 
 15   6   6   0   9   3   1   4   5    1    1   13    0    0   20    5   28
 2  24  14   7   0  15   7   0  11   3    3    4   15    7    0   30    0  344
 3  10   5   2   0   6   2   0   5   0    0    2    7    1    0   11    0  399
 4   9   4   2   0   5   2   0   4   0    0    2    6    1    0   10    0   28
 5   6   2   1   0   3   1   0   2   0    0    1    3    1    0    6    0   82
 6   9   4   2   0   5   2   0   4   0    0    2    6    1    0   10    0   42
```

But I am getting the following error message:

```
Error in scale.default(x, min(x), max(x) - min(x)) (from #4) : 
  length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using this data , your example works for me:

```
data <- matrix(sample(1:1000,17*6), ncol=17,nrow=6)
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  x <- data[i, ]
  data[i, ] <- scale(x, min(x), max(x)-min(x))
}
```

Here another option using scale , without a loop. You need just to provide a `scale` and a `center` with same columns that your matrix.

```
maxs <- apply(data, 2, max)    
mins <- apply(data, 2, min)
scale(data, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins)
```

**EDIT** how to access the result.

The scale returns a matrix with 2 attributes.  To get a data.frame, you need just to coerce the scale result to a data.frame.

```
dat.scale <- scale(data, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins)
dat.sacle <- as.data.frame(dat.scale)
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I assign the output of scale function to some variable then I am unable extract the data portion. I think there are several other attributes in the output from scale function.

Comment: @Shahzad your data is a matrix with 2 extra attributes. You can for example , use `as.vector(data)` to remove them.

Comment: @Shahzad are they really in the way? You can use `attributes(x) <- list(dim=dim(x))`

Comment: @MatthewPlourde yes. that 's why I said 'for example' .Thanks for your help. You suggestion is the way if you want to keep a matrix with the same dimensions.

Comment: @agstudy. Sorry. But, I am still unable to access the data using $ notation such as data$x1 gives  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.

Comment: @agstudy You don't need to `apply` to find the `min` and `max` of a numeric `data.frame` or `matrix`. Because it's just a vector with `dim` attributes you can just do `min(data)` , and `max(data)`.

Comment: @SimonO101 I don't get your point here. `min(data)` will give me just a scalar. I need a vector with the same number of columns of the origin matrix to set the `scale` argument ...

Comment: Oh, I thought you had to scale the data across the whole frame, this seems like data is scaled between 0 and 1 column by column? I think I don't understand `scale` properly and I need to go away and read. If I were trying to scale a matrix of values between 0 and 1 I would be using the minima and maxima of the whole matrix.

Comment: @agstudy i.e. I would just use `data <- 1 / max( data ) * data`

Comment: @SimonO101 thanks. this should work I think `(data-min(data)) / (max( data)-min(data) )`...But , here the question was about the use of `scale`.

Answer (score 4):

The `center` and `scale` arguments to `scale` have to have length equal to the number of columns in `x`. It looks like `data` is a `data.frame`, so your `x` has as many columns as your `data.frame` does and hence the conflict. You can get past this snag three ways:

- drop the row into an atomic vector before passing to `scale` (which will treat it as a single column): `scale(as.numeric(x), ...)`
- convert `data` into a `matrix`, which drops row extractions into atomic vectors automatically.
- use @agstudy's `apply` suggestion, which would work whether it's a `data.frame` or a `matrix` and is arguably the "right" way to do this in R.

Answer (score 0):

there is also another way to scale the data by creating a function

```
 data_norm<- function(x) {((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))}
 variables_norm<- as.data.frame(lapply(data[1:17], data_norm)) 
 summary(variables_norm)
```