# Scaling data in R, resulting in error: "length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'"

Tags: r, neural-network, scale

I am trying to scale the Hitters data from ISLR using the following code:

```
data = Hitters
apply(data,2,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
data = subset(data, !is.na(Salary))
apply(data,2,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

maxs <- apply(data, 2, max) 
mins <- apply(data, 2, min)

scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(data, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))
```

Which, I pulled from [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-a-neural-network-in-r-neuralnet-package/) R-Bloggers tutorial on neural networks (I am trying to build a predictive model for Salary in the Hitters data using NNs). However, I keep getting the error:

```
> scale(data, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins)
Error in scale.default(data, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins) : 
  length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'
```

I read a discussion of this scale function error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698756/scaling-data-in-r-gives-spurious-error-length-of-center-must-equal-the-number) on Stackoverflow, but do not understand why I am receiving this error since maxs and mins have the same columns as my matrix, i.e. the Hitters data.

Comment: The results of your maxs and mins are all character. How can such values be used in `scale`?

Comment: Some of the values you are trying to max / min are character variables. League, Division, NewLeague...

Comment: The `League`, `Division`, and `NewLeague` are all factors.  That is causing the results to become strings.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you remove the non-numeric columns...

```
data = Hitters
apply(data,2,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
data = subset(data, !is.na(Salary))
apply(data,2,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

# add this line to remove non-numeric columns.
data <- data[, sapply(data, is.numeric)]

maxs <- as.numeric(apply(data, 2, max) )
mins <- as.numeric(apply(data, 2, min))

scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(data, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @cory so you cannot use the scale function with factors?

Comment: What would it mean to scale the "League" variable? It's text. Here's a good answer on what scaling or standardizing variables does and why to do it... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/when-and-how-to-use-standardized-explanatory-variables-in-linear-regression